# I lost my purchased horse in Skyrim - please help?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to my horse if I ride another horse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38410/what-happens-to-my-horse-if-i-ride-another-horse)

While I was doing a quest called "The Battle For Fort Dunstad", I got off my horse outside of the fort so it won't get killed while I was killing the enemy. After I killed everyone, I saw a random horse and when I walked towards it, it said "A: Ride Horse". I accidentally pressed A and I mounted the horse. I dismounted it then fast traveled to a city to complete the quest. I went to Katla's Farm to find my horse for another quest but it wasn't there. Instead, the horse I accidentally mounted was there. I went back to Fort Dunstad and went on a scavenger hunt to find my horse all around that area but I still couldn't find it. I DON'T WANT TO BUY ANOTHER HORSE !! I love that horse T _ T

Answer (score 4):

Once you mount a new horse, that horse is registered as your current one. If you couldn't find your older horse after going back to where you left it, it's gone forever.

EDIT: After reading on the topic [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38410/what-happens-to-my-horse-if-i-ride-another-horse), it seems that your older horse should have returned to where you bought it.

Comment: I just went to Whiterun after reading your reply and I found my horse! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zyneste, remember to select my answer as the right one. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go back to where you bought it. A new (or the old horse whos walked back?) appears.

Unless its a special horse which cannot be recovered I would think.