# What happens to Shadowmere if I rode another horse in Falskaar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

Skyrim and Falskaar are two different places. Would I still be able to ride Shadowmere in Skyrim if I bought and rode a horse in Falskaar?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of [that one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38410/what-happens-to-my-horse-if-i-ride-another-horse). Falskaar seems to have different horse-related mechanics compared to the vanilla game and the official DLCs. For example, I can not summon Arvak in Falskaar. Close voters: Can you verify that the answers in [the other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38410/what-happens-to-my-horse-if-i-ride-another-horse) works the same for Falskaar?